# Discriminated Union of Generic type

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'd like to be able to use [union discrimination](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html) with a generic.  However, it doesn't seem to be working:

Example Code ([view on typescript playground)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Foo%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'foo'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fooProp%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Bar%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'bar'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20barProp%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20GenericThing%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20item%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20func%20%3D%20(genericThing%3A%20GenericThing%3CFoo%20%7C%20Bar%3E)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(genericThing.item.type%20%3D%3D%3D%20'foo')%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20genericThing.item.fooProp%3B%20%2F%2F%20this%20works%2C%20but%20type%20of%20genericThing%20is%20still%20GenericThing%3CFoo%20%7C%20Bar%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20fooThing%20%3D%20genericThing%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fooThing.item.fooProp%3B%20%2F%2Ferror!%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A):

```
interface Foo{
    type: 'foo';
    fooProp: string
}

interface Bar{
    type: 'bar'
    barProp: number
}

interface GenericThing<T> {
    item: T;
}


let func = (genericThing: GenericThing<Foo | Bar>) => {
    if (genericThing.item.type === 'foo') {

        genericThing.item.fooProp; // this works, but type of genericThing is still GenericThing<Foo | Bar>

        let fooThing = genericThing;
        fooThing.item.fooProp; //error!
    }
}
```

I was hoping that typescript would recognize that since I discriminated on the generic `item` property, that `genericThing` must be `GenericThing<Foo>`.

I'm guess this just isn't supported?

Also, kinda weird that after straight assignment, it `fooThing.item` loses it's discrimination.

Comment: What error do you get on that last line? Does extracting just the item from the genericThing, either at the top of the function or by destructuring in the arguments, make any difference?

Comment: @jonrsharpe open the typescript playground link and you can see it.  `fooProp does not exist on type ...`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### The problem

Type narrowing in discriminated unions is subject to several restrictions:

**No unwrapping of generics**

Firstly, if the type is generic, the generic will not be unwrapped to narrow a type: narrowing needs a union to work. So, for example this does not work:

```
let func = (genericThing:  GenericThing<'foo' | 'bar'>) => {
    switch (genericThing.item) {
        case 'foo':
            genericThing; // still GenericThing<'foo' | 'bar'>
            break;
        case 'bar':
            genericThing; // still GenericThing<'foo' | 'bar'>
            break;
    }
}
```

While this does:

```
let func = (genericThing: GenericThing<'foo'> | GenericThing<'bar'>) => {
    switch (genericThing.item) {
        case 'foo':
            genericThing; // now GenericThing<'foo'> !
            break;
        case 'bar':
            genericThing; // now  GenericThing<'bar'> !
            break;
    }
}
```

I suspect unwrapping a generic type that has a union type argument would cause all sorts of strange corner cases that the compiler team can't resolve in a satisfactory way.

**No narrowing by nested properties**

Even if we have a union of types, no narrowing will occur if we test on a nested property. A field type may be narrowed based on the test, but the root object will not be narrowed:

```
let func = (genericThing: GenericThing<{ type: 'foo' }> | GenericThing<{ type: 'bar' }>) => {
    switch (genericThing.item.type) {
        case 'foo':
            genericThing; // still GenericThing<{ type: 'foo' }> | GenericThing<{ type: 'bar' }>)
            genericThing.item // but this is { type: 'foo' } !
            break;
        case 'bar':
            genericThing;  // still GenericThing<{ type: 'foo' }> | GenericThing<{ type: 'bar' }>)
            genericThing.item // but this is { type: 'bar' } !
            break;
    }
}
```

### The solution

The solution is to use a custom type guard. We can make a pretty generic version of the type guard that would work for any type parameter that has a `type` field. Unfortunately, we can't make it for any generic type since it will be tied to `GenericThing`:

```
function isOfType<T extends { type: any }, TValue extends string>(
  genericThing: GenericThing<T>,
  type: TValue
): genericThing is GenericThing<Extract<T, { type: TValue }>> {
  return genericThing.item.type === type;
}

let func = (genericThing: GenericThing<Foo | Bar>) => {
  if (isOfType(genericThing, "foo")) {
    genericThing.item.fooProp;

    let fooThing = genericThing;
    fooThing.item.fooProp;
  }
};
```

Comment: oh man... that solution is rough!   Good to know it's possible though.   My solution is just to code against the nested object instead of trying to accept the narrowed generic. EG: having my function accept `Foo` (instead of `GenericThing<Foo>` directly if I need to do something discriminated with it

Comment: @NSjonas that is also an option :-)

Answer (score 7):

As @Titian explained the problem arises when what you really need is:

```
GenericThing<'foo'> | GenericThing<'bar'>
```

but you have something defined as:

```
GenericThing<'foo' | 'bar'>
```

Clearly if you only have two choices like this you can just expand it out yourself, but of course that isn't scalable.

Let's say I have a recursive tree with nodes. This is a simplification:

```
// different types of nodes
export type NodeType = 'section' | 'page' | 'text' | 'image' | ....;

// node with children
export type OutlineNode<T extends NodeType> = AllowedOutlineNodeTypes> = 
{
    type: T,
    data: NodeDataType[T],   // definition not shown

    children: OutlineNode<NodeType>[]
}
```

The types represented by `OutlineNode<...>` need to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), which they are because of the `type: T` property.

Let's say we have an instance of a node and we iterate through the children:

```
const node: OutlineNode<'page'> = ....;
node.children.forEach(child => 
{
   // check a property that is unique for each possible child type
   if (child.type == 'section') 
   {
       // we want child.data to be NodeDataType['section']
       // it isn't!
   }
})
```

Clearly in this case I don't want to define children with all possible node types.

An alternative is to 'explode out' the `NodeType` where we define children. Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to make this generic because I can't extract out the type name.

Instead you can do the following:

```
// create type to take 'section' | 'image' and return OutlineNode<'section'> | OutlineNode<'image'>
type ConvertToUnion<T> = T[keyof T];
type OutlineNodeTypeUnion<T extends NodeType> = ConvertToUnion<{ [key in T]: OutlineNode<key> }>;
```

Then the definition of `children` changes to become:

```
 children: OutlineNodeTypeUnion<NodeType>[]
```

Now when you iterate through the children it's an expanded out definition of all possibilities and the descriminated union type guarding kicks in by itself.

Why not just use a typeguard? 1) You don't really need to. 2) If using something like an angular template you don't want a bazillion calls to your typeguard. This way does in fact allow automatic type narrowing within `*ngIf` but unfortunately not `ngSwitch`

Comment: Defining a type of union types was precisely what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a good point that the expression `genericThing.item` is seen as a `Foo` inside the `if` block. I thought that it works only after extracting it to a variable (`const item = genericThing.item`). Probably a better behaviour of latest versions of TS.

This enables the pattern matching like in the function `area` in the official documentation on [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) and that is actually missing in C# (in v7, a `default` case is still necessary in a `switch` statement like this).

Indeed, the weird thing is that `genericThing` is still seen undiscriminated (as a `GenericThing<Foo | Bar>` instead of `GenericThing<Foo>`), even inside the `if` block where `item` is a `Foo`! Then the error with `fooThing.item.fooProp;` does not surprise me.

I guess the TypeScript team has still some improvements to do to support this situation.