# Discriminated unions type matching

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I can't seem to match the types of the param the function takes and the payload:

```
type SelectCase = {
  type: 'selectCase';
}

type UpdateNotification = {
  type: 'updateNotification';
  payload: {
    title: string;
    message: string;
  }
}

type Message = SelectCase | UpdateNotification;

const someFn = <TMessageType extends Message['type']>(
    messageType: TMessageType,
    onMessage: (
        payload?: Extract<Message, { type: TMessageType }> extends {
            payload: infer TPayload;
        }
            ? TPayload
            : undefined
    ) => void
) => {
  const handleMessage = (message: Message) => {
    if(message.type === messageType) {
      // does not work
      onMessage(message.payload);
    }
  }
};
```

This is a reduced example, I have more than 20 types of messages. Any idea why this does not work?

I have tried type predicates and call signatures but it still errors.

Comment: I'm playing around with this a little and having some trouble, so i'll follow up when I find an answer. In the mean time, this thread is proving helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870423/discriminated-union-of-generic-type

Comment: Hmm, this is sort of a nightmare version of the issue in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and I can't figure out how to address it with the fix mentioned in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  As a workaround you could write a type guard function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkkQPW); does that work for you or am I missing something? (Please mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I saw that thread but I don't believe it's directly related, at least I was not able to make it work.
@jcalz I try to make something similar to ms/TS#47109, but it still throws an error :( https://tsplay.dev/wEBdVN

Comment: Right, I suspect the ms/TS#47109 solution will not let you avoid a type guard function, since there's no good way to relate `Message<K>` and `Message<P>` for two independent generic types `K` and `P`.  [This](https://tsplay.dev/w6vYvw) is the closest I can get, and it's really the same as my earlier solution except that it tries to use ms/TS#47109.  So, shall I write up an answer showing how to write a type guard function to deal with this?  Or do you think I'm still missing something about the question? (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me, thanks)

Comment: @jcalz Both of your solutions seems the be working great, the only issue is that it does not error when you call someFn with a function with an incorrect type, take a look at this https://tsplay.dev/mbQq4N It also happens with the other solution.

Comment: I don't see you calling it incorrectly, please see [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters). Even so it looks like you might be asking a followup question which is out of scope here.  I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @jcalz Awesome, thank you for the info, I didn't know that. Thank you for your help! Do you have to answer so I can mark your answer as correct? I don't think I can do that with a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is TypeScript's lack of direct support for *correlated [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) types* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Essentially the type checker cannot easily be made to understand that the check `message.type === messageType` should [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) `message` to the member of the `Message` union whose `payload` property can be handled by `onMessage()`. The type of `message` becomes *correlated* to the type of `messageType` after that check without being known specifically.  But there's no easy way to convey such information to the compiler.

Often you can work around this issue with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and some refactoring of types as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), but I couldn't get that to work here (if someone *does* get this to work, let me know).

---

So instead, I think the best thing we can do is write a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to say that `message.type === messageType` will narrow `message` appropriately.  Here's one way to do it:

First, I'm going to copy your conditional type for `onMessage()`'s parameter into a utility type we can reuse:

```
type CorrespondingPayload<K extends Message['type']> =
    Extract<Message, { type: K }> extends {
        payload: infer TPayload;
    } ? TPayload : undefined
```

And now the custom type guard function looks like this:

```
function sameType<K extends Message['type']>(
    message: Message, messageType: K
): message is Message & { type: K, payload: CorrespondingPayload<K> } {
    return message.type === messageType;
}
```

If `sameType(message, messageType)` returns `true`, then `message` will be narrowed to a type where `payload` is known to be of type `CorrespondingPayload<K>`.  Let's use it:

```
const someFn = <K extends Message['type']>(
    messageType: K,
    onMessage: (payload?: CorrespondingPayload<K>) => void
) => {
    const handleMessage = (message: Message) => {
        if (sameType(message, messageType)) {
            onMessage(message.payload); // okay
        }
    }
};
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)