# conditional return type not valid with prisma

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I have the following *conditional* type inside my **Express** app:

```
type SerializedFunction<Serialized, Unserialized> 
    = <B extends boolean>(serialize: B) 
    => Promise<B extends true 
        ? (Serialized   | null) 
        : (Unserialized | null)
    >;
```

It is being attached to a function like so:

```
import type { examples } from "@prisma/client";

interface DataSerialized{
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
}

const data: SerializedFunction<DataSerialized, examples> = async serialize => {
    // Return non-serialized data.
    if(!serialized) return await prisma.examples.findFirst({ 
        // ...
    });

    const example = await prisma.examples.findFirst({
        // ...
        select: {
            foo: true,
            bar: true,
        }
    });

    if(!example) return null;
    return {
        ...example,
        bar: await doSomethingWithBar(bar)
    };
}
```

The purpose of `SerializedFunction` is to set the return type of the function to either `DataSerialized` or `examples` depending on whether or not the function parameter is set to true (or null if no result is found).

However, when I try to implement this, I receive the following **TypeScript** error:

```
Type examples | { 
    // The object specified in the first "findFirst" call...
}
is not assignable to type 'B extends true ? DataSerialized : examples'.

Type 'examples' is not assignable to type 'B extends true ? DataSerialized : examples'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **discriminating union**.

The way it works is that you define the same structure for both (or multiple options based on different discriminating types), but there's a type that *discriminates* (determines) which specific sub-type is expected, based on "static" values. You do so by "hard coding" a value (aka literal) in the TS type (usually it's a type (definition), but in this case true, false, or a "string")

Pseudo, but the  way you would implement a type like that is:

```
type DataSerialized = {...}
type ExampleType = {...}

type MyReturnType = {
   serialized: true;
   data: DataSerialized
} | {
   serialized: false;
   data: ExampleType
}
```

[TypeScript docs for more on discriminating unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)

Comment: What if the type is not known? The function type I've defined is supposed to be used generically.

Comment: If you want to narrow down generics, you will need to do so by some conditional checks, similar to what you've done already in your code. You can learn more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870423/discriminated-union-of-generic-type