# Choose type according to generic property in typescript

Tags: typescript

How can I choose type according to generic property?

```
enum AnimalType {
  DOG,
  CAT,
  FROG,
  SNAKE,
}

const dog = {
  type: AnimalType.DOG, // type property exists for all animals. other properties are vary for different animals
  legs: 4,
}

const cat = {
  type: AnimalType.CAT,
  tail: 1,
}

const frog = {
  type: AnimalType.FROG,
  canSwim: true,
  tail: 0,
}

const snake = {
  type: AnimalType.SNAKE,
  tail: 'looong',
  age: 2,
}

type Animal<AnimalType> = typeof dog | typeof cat | typeof frog | typeof snake // how to rewrite this type definition?
```

How to infer type according to AnimalType? for example `Animal<AnimalType.DOG>` should be equal to `typeof dog`

It's possible with conditional types:

```
type Animal<T extends AnimalType> = T extends AnimalType.DOG ? typeof dog : T extends AnimalType.CAT ? typeof cat : T extends AnimalType.FROG ? typeof frog : T extends AnimalType.SNAKE ? typeof snake : unknown
```

But it looks too long and totally unreadable. I hope there is a better solution

Comment: Your `dog`/`cat`/etc all have `type` as `AnimalType` so the compiler doesn't know how to distinguish them; you can remedy that with `as const` and then use `Extract`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mALL8N).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discriminated Union of Generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870423/discriminated-union-of-generic-type)

Comment: @possum not exactly. Previous answer is more relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably intended

```
const dog = {
  type: AnimalType.DOG,
  legs: 4,
}
```

to have the type `{type: AnimalType.DOG, legs: number}`.  But TypeScript infers the type of `AnimalType.DOG` to be the wider [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) type `AnimalType` instead of the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `AnimalType.DOG`.

That means someone could write `dog.type = AnimalType.CAT`, which is not good.  And it also means that `typeof dog` has no information you can use from which to compute `Animal<T>`.

To fix this, you need to tell the compiler that `type` should be given a more specific literal type.  The usual approach for that is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the literal in question.  You could do that for the full object literal `{type: AnimalType.DOG, legs: 4} as const`, if you want the compiler to enforce that `dog.legs` is always exactly `4`.  But at the bare minimum we should do it for the `type` property.  Yielding this:

```
const dog = { type: AnimalType.DOG as const, legs: 4 };
const cat = { type: AnimalType.CAT as const, tail: 1 };
const frog = { type: AnimalType.FROG as const, canSwim: true, tail: 0 };
const snake = { type: AnimalType.SNAKE as const, tail: 'looong', age: 2 };
```

Now the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `typeof dog | typeof cat | typeof frog | typeof snake` looks like:

```
type SomeAnimal = typeof dog | typeof cat | typeof frog | typeof snake;
/* type SomeAnimal = {
    type: AnimalType.DOG;
    legs: number;
} | {
    type: AnimalType.CAT;
    tail: number;
} | {
    type: AnimalType.FROG;
    canSwim: boolean;
    tail: number;
} | {
    type: AnimalType.SNAKE;
    tail: string;
    age: number;
} */
```

which lets us implement `Animal` via the union-filtering [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union):

```
type Animal<T extends AnimalType> =
  Extract<SomeAnimal, { type: T }>;
```

Let's test it out:

```
type Dog = Animal<AnimalType.DOG>;
/* type Dog = {
    type: AnimalType.DOG;
    legs: number;
} */
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWECGAbAKgTwA7CgbwCgooARAeQHEAaIqAYRjRuIDEAlS5qAZQDkYA0gFEaAXwIEAxgHsQAZwAuUACbSA5lAC8+KAuzAAXLATJ0+gHTkKUJHKgz5CqlBTA1cowBYoogNxTZRXskJW08XX0jOERUTBxzBjQbOwdFZwUkeBQjAEYff1SlADMAJ3UtHT0cKJNYi3ZKZPtAp2CQbgB3RCMFErBgdMzsqAAGfIDHKDkQJABrXDCI6uMYs3i+QSEmwsGsowByFGljkDV95yQ1QygAJnGCKtxuaQhgaNMKx+kilXKAHyWwG+wSUAK+P1K-0BwOmc2A-gA9AAqQE8F5vWooCqEYjER41VZxYCWSj+XEuNweKDgCAAI2AJX8oigAJxuPxK1MRISjDJ7KGRhp9MZBGZrNoeMinLq8QaFD5xEkSHaXQgRlpx1cyoVugF1MgwqZLPwEsBBK5Fg2wh1GT2U168FOOsu1yFDKNSIREke0pQAB4ksAAB4KUDKOzvGXAAB8WloQhDJSQkgUfuer0jKGc4Q5SVE0f8D30pHK2kzfsz3KsBYIyNRJFLJvJHMrFisOtc7kFBvdoqgnoIQA)